# How can I finish the edge of a mirrored wall?

Tags: mirror

I am having a full wall in my foyer covered with mirror, and I am curious to know how to finish the end of a fully mirrored wall?  The wall ends at a corner that leads into the sitting room. So from the sitting room, the edge of the mirror will be visible. I hope this makes sense?

In other words the foyer wall to the right of the entrance wall will be mirrored.  That wall is about 8 feet long.  When the wall ends, you turn a corner to enter the sitting room.  It is that corner that I am referring to; I want to be sure that the edge of mirror is finished correctly and also that visually it looks good from the sitting room.

Comment: Probably using a piece or two of trim. Is it ending with an outside corner? How much room between the corner and the end of the mirror? How far off the wall does the front of the mirror stick out?

Answer (score 3):

I think in this case the best solution is to use a timber profile - L shape trim. You stick it on the edge with some liquid nails glue and so it covers the wall from one side and goes over a mirror edge on the other[image]
the ones in the middle in the picture

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is **corner trim** (sometimes referred to as "L" trim).

[image]

The picture is a pretty extreme example.  It has a lot of character but I like it for a mirror.  Smaller lip over the mirrored side and circles on the other.   I am not saying get this piece - just an example.

Corner trim is a pretty generic word but it basically fits over a corner, and has two sides.  When looking at corner trim you can get very different scopes of product - from thick traditional wood to thin modern metals.

I know it depends on the look and feel of the room but I would look for a thinner metal corner trim for mirrors.  (You could also call a local metal shop that could custom make one if this corner is a traffic feature point of the house)  You want this trim to go anywhere from 1/4 to an inch over the mirror to protect the mirror and people and then on the walls side it needs a good inch to bind.  I would just glue it down with liquid nails - no screws.

The reason I prefer metal vs wood here is that being a corner the wood has a greater chance of having issues - cracked from being hit, warping a bit, not protecting mirror enough.